# How to morph the response returned to Observable by angular-in-memory-web-api after HTTP request to JSON?

Tags: json, angular, interceptor, angular2-observables

I can definitely map the Observable and transform the response in whatever way I like, but while going through the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) I came across

> responseInterceptor

So, I wonder If I can send some configurations and get a JSON response itself without writing my extra function.

There isn't much written about `responseInterceptor` or how to use it.
If not this, then is there some other way to do this using `angular-in-memory-web-api` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the response before it's returned to observable with the help of this interceptor

> You can morph the response returned by the default HTTP methods,
>   called by `collectionHandler`, to suit your needs by adding a
>   `responseInterceptor` method to your `InMemoryDbService` class. The
>   `collectionHandler` calls your interceptor like this:
>
> ```
> responseOptions = this.responseInterceptor(responseOptions, requestInfo);
> ```

To test it's working you can add this code to your `InMemoryDbService`

```
responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo):ResponseInterceptor {
  console.log("call responseInterceptor");
  return res;
}
```

Comment: While testing the above, I see a `res` of type `ResponseOptions` returning but the function is expecting `ResponseInterceptor` type return. This is also getting flagged by my typeScript.

Comment: I am trying what you suggested, inside the `responseInterceptor()` I see `res`, and I modify it and make a different JSON object using the data in res and return the newly created `object`. But the place I do an HTTP request, say: `http.get(url).map( reponse => // somecode ). catch((error)=>log error//)`. I keep getting this error: `{"ok":false,"statusText":"Unknown Status","url":"api/sessionData/1"}`. What am I doing wrong? Not supposed to modify the return from the responseInterceptor()?

Comment: Yes, It definitely works, I created my JSON object and assigned it the body of `res`. like: `res.body` = newOb; and returned the `res` itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The in-memory-web-api and ResponseInterceptor from Angular are for faking / manipulating requests in test scenarios.

After all, it is not quite clear to me, what your purpose is.

Comment: If it intercepts the XHR calls, shouldn't it be `requestInterceptor`? I just want to know if there is a way to return a JSON (just beacuse I came across `responseInterceptor`) instead of an Observable after an HTTP request (which is handled by the angular-in-memory-web-api).

Comment: You are right, I guess. I updated my answer. Still, it is not quite clear what you try to achieve. Do you maybe have some code that you can show us? That would help make things clearer.

Comment: I want to modify the data `(response) ` contained inside the returning observable. Make it like my desired JSON format. So I guess, this could be done inside the `responseInterceptor()`.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#extract-data

Comment: Yes, seen  it. I want to manipulate the `response` before it even reaches the `http method caller, say: get()`. So, I think before it comes here, it comes to responseInterceptor(). And I should be able to manipulate it like whatever way I want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you had asked for some code. The accepted answer solved my issue. I am sorry I couldn't explain to you my question.